# OpenGL on a 64-bit Raspberry Pi 4 without X

Tags: c++, opengles

I wrote a 3D visualization program in C++ called [ahrs-visualizer](https://github.com/DavidEGrayson/ahrs-visualizer) back in 2012 for a 32-bit Raspberry Pi, basing my code on the official OpenGL example code that came with Raspbian.  It does not require X: you run it in text-only mode, and it displays 3D graphics on top of the text.  It worked well for years.

I'd like to get it compiling on a 64-bit Raspberry Pi 4 with Raspberry Pi OS Bullseye, but the type `EGL_DISPMANX_WINDOW_T` does not exist on that platform.  Here is the OpenGL initialization function I wrote which uses that type and which can no longer be compiled:

```c
// Sets the display, OpenGL|ES context and screen stuff
static void opengl_init(void)
{
    EGLBoolean result;
    EGLint num_config;

    static EGL_DISPMANX_WINDOW_T nativewindow;

    DISPMANX_ELEMENT_HANDLE_T dispman_element;
    DISPMANX_DISPLAY_HANDLE_T dispman_display;
    DISPMANX_UPDATE_HANDLE_T dispman_update;

    static const EGLint attribute_list[] =
        {
            EGL_RED_SIZE, 8,
            EGL_GREEN_SIZE, 8,
            EGL_BLUE_SIZE, 8,
            EGL_ALPHA_SIZE, 8,
            EGL_SURFACE_TYPE, EGL_WINDOW_BIT,
            EGL_NONE
        };

    EGLConfig config;

    // get an EGL display connection
    display = eglGetDisplay(EGL_DEFAULT_DISPLAY);
    if (display == EGL_NO_DISPLAY)
    {
        throw std::runtime_error("Failed to get display.  eglGetDisplay failed.");
    }

    // initialize the EGL display connection
    result = eglInitialize(display, NULL, NULL);
    if (result == EGL_FALSE)
    {
        throw std::runtime_error("Failed to initialize display.  eglInitialize failed.");
    }

    // get an appropriate EGL frame buffer configuration
    result = eglChooseConfig(display, attribute_list, &config, 1, &num_config);
    if (result == EGL_FALSE)
    {
        throw std::runtime_error("Failed to choose config.  eglChooseConfig failed.");
    }

    // create an EGL rendering context
    context = eglCreateContext(display, config, EGL_NO_CONTEXT, NULL);
    if (context == EGL_NO_CONTEXT)
    {
        throw std::runtime_error("Failed to create context.  eglCreateContext failed.");
    }

    // create an EGL window surface
    int32_t success = graphics_get_display_size(0 /* LCD */, &screen_width, &screen_height);
    if (success < 0)
    {
        throw std::runtime_error("Failed to get display size.");
    }

    VC_RECT_T dst_rect = rect_width_height(screen_width, screen_height);
    VC_RECT_T src_rect = rect_width_height(screen_width<<16, screen_height<<16);

    dispman_display = vc_dispmanx_display_open(0 /* LCD */);
    dispman_update = vc_dispmanx_update_start(0);

    dispman_element = vc_dispmanx_element_add (dispman_update, dispman_display,
                                               0/*layer*/, &dst_rect, 0/*src*/,
                                               &src_rect, DISPMANX_PROTECTION_NONE, 0 /*alpha*/, 0/*clamp*/, (DISPMANX_TRANSFORM_T)0/*transform*/);

    nativewindow.element = dispman_element;
    nativewindow.width = screen_width;
    nativewindow.height = screen_height;
    vc_dispmanx_update_submit_sync(dispman_update);

    surface = eglCreateWindowSurface(display, config, &nativewindow, NULL);
    if(surface == EGL_NO_SURFACE)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "eglCreateWindowSurface returned ELG_NO_SURFACE.  "
                "Try closing other OpenGL programs.\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    // connect the context to the surface
    result = eglMakeCurrent(display, surface, surface, context);
    if (result == EGL_FALSE)
    {
        throw std::runtime_error("Failed to connect to the surface.");
    }

    glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 0.5);   // set background colors
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT); // clear buffers
    glShadeModel(GL_FLAT);

    // Enable back face culling.
    glEnable(GL_CULL_FACE);
}
```

Apparently someone working on Raspberry Pi OS decided to make a breaking change to `eglCreateWindowSurface`.  The third argument no longer accepts a `EGL_DISPMANX_WINDOW_T *`: it must be a `EGLNativeWindowType` instead.  That type is defined in `EGL/eglplatform.h`.  Since `EGL_NO_X11` is *not* defined, that type is a `Window` object that comes from some X headers.  However *I don't want to use X*.

I don't believe that just defining `EGL_NO_X11` when I compile my programs is valid... I believe I would also need to recompile the EGL library.

Can someone tell me how to get the code above compiling on a 64-bit Raspberry Pi 4, or point to me to some working OpenGL example code in C or C++ that does the same thing?  (For the purposes of this question, the code should *not* require the user to run X.  But I might give up on that goal eventually.)